# Passing variable length argument list to another function

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have made a separate function display() for displaying the numbers and wanted to send the initialized
argument pointer to this function.I am not getting the expected result. What is going wrong here?
I am using gcc version 10.1.0 (GCC)

```
/* Expected OUTPUT */
99 + 68 -> Total = 167
11 + 79 + 32-> Total = 122
23 + 34 + 45 + 56 + 78 -> Total = 236 

/* Getting OUTPUT */
99 + 68 -> Total = 224
11 + 79 + 32 -> Total = 1410200528
23 + 34 + 45 + 56 + 78 -> Total = -1056735662
```

My code is :

```
/* Program in which the variable length list is passed to another function */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdarg.h>

int sum(int, ...);
void display(int,va_list);

int main(void)
{
    printf("\b\b-> Total = %d\n",sum(2,99,68));
    printf("\b\b-> Total = %d\n",sum(3,11,79,32));
    printf("\b\b-> Total = %d\n",sum(5,23,34,45,56,78));

    return 0;
}

int sum(int num, ...)
{
    int i;
    va_list ap;
    int arg,total = 0;
    va_start(ap,num);
    display(num,ap);

    for(i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        arg=va_arg(ap,int);
        total+=arg;
    }

    va_end(ap);
    return total;
}

void display(int num,va_list ap)
{
    int i,argument;
    for(i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        argument=va_arg(ap,int);
        printf("%d + ",argument);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is strict from [C11 7.16p3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html):

> The object `ap` [of type `va_list`]  may be passed as an argument to another function; if that function invokes the va_arg macro with parameter ap, the value of ap in the calling function is **indeterminate and shall be passed to the `va_end` macro prior to any further reference to ap**.

The code:

```
display(num,ap);
va_arg(ap, ...);
```

is invalid - once you pass `va_list` to another function, you can *only* call `va_end`. You could take a pointer to `va_list`.

```
{
    ...
    display(num, &ap);
    va_arg(ap, int); // ok
    va_end(ap);
}
void display(int num, va_list *ap) {
    va_arg(*ap, int); // ok
}
```

But you are iterating `va_list` *twice* - once in display and once in `sum`. `va_list` remembers it's position, so to iterate the list twice you have to have two `va_list` initialized from the start. The simplest in your case is to initialize `va_list` twice. So you can do:

```
int sum(int num, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, num);
    display(num, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    int total = 0;
    va_start(ap, num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        int arg = va_arg(ap, int);
        total += arg;
    }
    va_end(ap);

    return total;
}

void display(int num, va_list ap)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        int argument = va_arg(ap,int);
        printf("%d + ",argument);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution and answer.

Comment: What difference does it make if I wrote `int i; for(i=0; i<num; i++)` instead of `for(int i=0; i<num; i++)` . Also for `argument` variable. I could have declared it before the for loop.

Comment: `What difference does it make` Technically: none.